# C# 'Object' does not contain a definition for 'position'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn to make a game using Unity so I come across a tutorial online but I faced a problem with Parallax Scrolling. The following is my code:

```
public class ScrollingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(2, 2);
    public Vector2 direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);
    public bool isLinkedToCamera = false;
    public bool isLooping = false;

    private List<SpriteRenderer> backgroundPart;

    void Start()
    {
        if (isLooping)
        {
            backgroundPart = new List<SpriteRenderer>();

            for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
            {
                Transform child = transform.GetChild(i);
                SpriteRenderer r = child.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

                if (r != null)
                {
                    backgroundPart.Add(r);
                }
            }

            backgroundPart = backgroundPart.OrderBy(t => t.position.x).ToList();
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(
          speed.x * direction.x,
          speed.y * direction.y,
          0);

        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(movement);

        if (isLinkedToCamera)
        {
            Camera.main.transform.Translate(movement);
        }

        if (isLooping)
        {
            SpriteRenderer firstChild = backgroundPart.FirstOrDefault();

            if (firstChild != null)
            {
                if (firstChild.transform.position.x < Camera.main.transform.position.x)
                {
                    if (firstChild.IsVisibleFrom(Camera.main) == false)
                    {
                        SpriteRenderer lastChild = backgroundPart.LastOrDefault();

                        Vector3 lastPosition = lastChild.transform.position;
                        Vector3 lastSize = (lastChild.bounds.max - lastChild.bounds.min);

                        firstChild.transform.position = new Vector3(lastPosition.x + lastSize.x, firstChild.transform.position.y, firstChild.transform.position.z);

                        backgroundPart.Remove(firstChild);
                        backgroundPart.Add(firstChild);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I have an error on the line:

```
backgroundPart = backgroundPart.OrderBy(t => t.position.x).ToList();
```

The Error code is "CS1061" whereby it says "'object' does not contain a definition for 'position' and no extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I was wondering where have I gone wrong? I was following the tutorial step by step. Been searching for a solution but can't find any. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How the class `SpriteRenderer` is defined, will it contains definition for `position`

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your background Part List as List of Type SpriteRenderer:

```
backgroundPart = new List<SpriteRenderer>();
```

So if you access like this:

```
backgroundPart = backgroundPart.OrderBy(t => t.position.x).ToList();
```

t is an object of Type SpriteRenderer. Make sure that your class SpriteRenderer has a Property which is called position. If this is not the case you get this exception.

Normally Properties a written in CamelCase and start with upper letter. Maybe you just misstype it:

Try:

```
backgroundPart = backgroundPart.OrderBy(t => t.Position.X).ToList();
```

**UPDATE:**

As Scott Chamberlain explains in comment below, Unity uses public fields instead of Properties. So this won't be a problem here.

Further make sure the tutorial is up to date and uses the same Unity-Version etc. like you do. Maybe Unity Framework change the name or structure of Properties or other Elements and you need to access this different now.

Comment: Unity frequently exposes public fields instead of properties so you will frequently see lowercase public members in it. However I think the first sentence of your last paragraph is the correct issue, the tutorial is outdated and [there is no longer a position field on the SpriteRenderer object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Probably it's old, maybe I'll try search somemore tutorials. Thanks a bunch!